# What does the secret have to contain for `AWS::RDS::DBProxy AuthFormat`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

To create an [`AWS::RDS::DBProxy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbproxy.html) using CloudFormation, you need to provide a SecretsManager Secret as the authentication method. In the below example, it's the secret pointed to by `BootstrapProxySecretArn`:

```yaml
Resources:
  TestDBProxy:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
    Properties:
      DBProxyName: !Ref ProxyName
      EngineFamily: MYSQL
      RoleArn:
        !Ref BootstrapSecretReaderRoleArn
      Auth:
        - {AuthScheme: SECRETS, SecretArn: !Ref BootstrapProxySecretArn, IAMAuth: DISABLED}
      VpcSubnetIds:
```

But the CloudFormation docs don't explain what this secret needs to contain. Is it a secret containing the password for that database username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **templates** for different databases for secrete manager are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html). For MySQL it would be:

```
{
  "engine": "mysql",
  "host": "<required: instance host name/resolvable DNS name>",
  "username": "<required: username>",
  "password": "<required: password>",
  "dbname": "<optional: database name. If not specified, defaults to None>",
  "port": "<optional: TCP port number. If not specified, defaults to 3306>"
}
```

Alternatively, you can always **use AWS console to create the secret automatically** for you for your database, and inspect its structure which then you can re-use in CloudFormation.

Comment: This page looks like it's for secret *rotation* specifically, is it applicable for authentication using secrets generally?

Comment: @Migwell  You can double check with automated creation of the secret using AWS console.

Comment: Ah yep the Secrets Manager console helped me generate an appropriate secret. I am using an RDS cluster so none of the examples in your link were appropriate, but the console showed the right format.

Comment: @Migwell Thanks. So you are using Aurora?

Comment: Yep. Postgres Aurora RDS.